# Appcelerator Studio cannot create new mobile app project

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-mobile, appcelerator-alloy, appcelerator-studio

**Error**
Plug-in com.appcelerator.titanium.desktop was unable to load class

Answer (score 0):

Did you try CLI ?

Open a terminal and enter:

```
appc new
```

Answer (score 0):

What version of Appcelerator Studio are you using? Looks like

*com.appcelerator.titanium.desktop* is a very old plugin which is not there in the latest studio.

I would suggest you take the latest version of Appcelerator Studio 4.8.0